# German acronym for "Neben Bei"?

Tags: usage

I'm looking for an German acronym for "Neben Bei".

"Ganz neben bei..." = "ganz n.B'? or "ganz N.b.'?

Usage example: "(**n.B**., ich werde auch dabei sein)" or "(**N.b**., ich werde auch dabei sein)"

"Neben Bei" = "just on the side (i.e. "side note"): I will also be there."

Perhaps similar with: z.B. = "zum Beispiel" and/or "z.Zt." = "zur Zeit"

Comment: N.b. may expand to "[Nota bene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene)", too.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. your question is based on a false assumption: that "nebenbei" is two words as in "neben bei". I left this in your question because otherwise the whole question would immediatly collapse and make no sense any further.

Comment: The abbreviation NB (or n.b. or N.B.) has the same meaning in English and in German. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene .

Answer (score 2):

The adverb [*nebenbei*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nebenbei), meaning *apropos* or *by the way*, is a single word. This implies that there cannot be an acronym of it. (By definition an acronym is formed from the initial letters or syllables of multiple words.)

In fact, there is not even an official abbreviation of *nebenbei*. The one you had in mind, *n.b.* (also *N.B.* or *NB*), is already reserved for [*nota bene*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/notabene).

Comment: Aha, so, would a typical German reader also understand "n.b." as "by the way"? or an "adjustment" of capitalization help with clarity? (z.B. "N.b.", "n.B." I have seen "n.b." often enough... somehow, my memory usually associated this usage with German Thank you, MfG, John

Comment: @JohnHopkins I don't think `n.b.` is widely known, so many people will not understand it without looking it up. And no, a German reader will not understand it as an acronym for "nebenbei" (= by the way). I personally would not even use "nebenbei" in this sense. I would rather use "übrigens" or "nebenbei bemerkt". I would use "nebenbei" only with a meaning of something like "without much effort at the same time", or "along the way".

Comment: No, it would not be understood. It would be understood (if at all) as what Björn explains, as 'nota bene', thus "pay attention", "please mind" or "mark my words". Also see Bodo's comment

Comment: I would recognise NB, but not in that form, only as “NB: something that needs to be noted”.